# Implicit Sanitization of Inputs In Rails: Why do these examples from the API work the way they do?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection, sanitization

Thanks for your help as I bootstrap my way into Ruby and Rails.

In the Rails API for [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), there's a section on Conditions that's meant to simply cover syntax for interactions with ActiveRecord. But the example they've used includes a very interesting (to me) primer on input-sanitization in Ruby/Rails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.authenticate_unsafely(user_name, password)
    where("user_name = '#{user_name}' AND password = '#{password}'").first
  end

  def self.authenticate_safely(user_name, password)
    where("user_name = ? AND password = ?", user_name, password).first
  end

  def self.authenticate_safely_simply(user_name, password)
    where(:user_name => user_name, :password => password).first
  end
end
```

Following this example code, they explain that:

> "The authenticate_safely and authenticate_safely_simply both will sanitize the user_name and password before inserting them in the query, which will ensure that an attacker can’t escape the query and fake the login (or worse)."

I totally get how this sanitization of inputs is a Good Thing in preventing injection attacks. What I do not understand is where and how this implicit sanitization is happening, given that there are no special methods being called to pre-process the input data. The various example methods appear to have nearly identical semantics and yet the variations in form have huge effects on safety because of the way that they're parsed. I'm assuming that these variations in form are similar *in effect* to the difference between using single-quotes and double-quotes around a string containing escape characters. But can anybody help me get smarter, faster, by understanding in general terms (or rather: at the logical level, rather than inside the interpreter) what's actually happening under the hood to make this so?

Also, to what extent are any of these differences dependent on Rails-specific constructs, rather than the underlying Ruby?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input sanitization is a feature provided by Active Record known as [prepared statements or parameterized statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Most database access libraries provide this natively, however, Active Record chooses to  *emulate* this feature using string-mangling mechanisms. See `build_where` in `active_record/relation/query_methods.rb` and backtrack your way to `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` (via its `sanitize_sql` alias) in `active_record/base.rb`. (Many thanks to [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576665/implicit-sanitization-of-inputs-in-rails-why-do-these-examples-from-the-api-wor#comment12144174_9576882) for the research.)

Instead of the old-style practice of building query strings as *strings* in the application, you have a static *template* query with parameters. When you call the query, you supply the parameters and Active Record will construct a safe query for the SQL engine to execute.

You could do this task yourself -- myriad PHP programmers choose to eschew their similar [PDO database access layer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). However, many programmers cannot get this correct: [there are roughly 1500 SQL Injection flaws](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=sql+injection&search_type=last3years&cves=on) discovered in the last three years and my local [CVE database](http://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/index.html) shows over 5000 instances of programs vulnerable to SQL injection attacks since MITRE started keeping track. Nearly all of these were due entirely to people who chose to write their own SQL code by hand and did not properly sanitize their input. (I didn't personally inspect each one but I can't recall seeing any flaws in the ORM or database access layers that allow SQL injection attacks through. But to be on the conservative side, I chose "Nearly all".)

Fellow stacker [Jeff Atwood equates old-style SQL queries as the `goto` of database programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html):

> Non-parameterized SQL is the GoTo statement of database programming. Don't do it, and make sure your coworkers don't either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ActiveRecord doesn't actually use prepared statements and bound parameters, it does string wrangling. Start at `build_where` in `active_record/relation/query_methods.rb` and backtrack your way to `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` (via its `sanitize_sql` alias) in `active_record/base.rb`.

Comment: @muistooshort: hey, long time no see. Many thanks for the correction. I'm a little disappointed in the Active Record folks for not using the native database libraries to provide this, but they must have figured if they had to write it for one database they might as well use it for all databases to find bugs more quickly.

Comment: The ActiveRecord people seem to hate databases (or they're just blinded by silly ideology): no FKs, no CHECKs, no triggers, race conditions in the validation system, `sanitize_sql` is private (!), ... I think INSERTs sometimes use native placeholders though. The placeholder standardization logic should (IMO) be pushed down to the drivers. I find myself pushing AR out of the way in favor of raw SQL for anything non-trivial due to AR's extremely limited understanding of SQL. That's enough ranting for now, I have to go chase some damn kids of my lawn.

Comment: @muis: I tried using FKs with AR when I first started RoR but it drastically complicated migrations. I wish they could invent a magical mechanism to apply them when I want them and suspend them when it makes sense. Triggers might be difficult to represent but it would be nice to have. `sanitize_sql` being private makes a ton of sense to me -- it helps discourage PHP-style roll-your-own queries except under extreme duress. (Maybe that's just my wishful thinking.) Good luck with the kids on your lawn; the kids around here have no respect.

Comment: I use FKs, CHECKs, triggers, and the whole nine yards: I refuse to cripple my applications just because the people that built AR are too adolescent to properly work with a database. Doing it all by hand is a  PITA but nothing compared to a database full of broken data. Once you need anything more complicated than `select *`, you either do it all in Ruby (which is insane) or you do string interpolation in your SQL because AR's opinion and ideology get in the way of getting real work done. Those kids will learn respect when they pay us crotchety old men to fix their broken apps and databases :)